# Collecting characters form a string and converting them to integers

Tags: java, arrays, string, int, compare

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int rounds, antonia = 100, david = 100;
    int rolla, rolld;
    String score;
    String[] scorenospace;
    System.out.println("How many rounds would you like to play? (1-15)");
    rounds = scan.nextInt();
    while (rounds > 0) {
        score = scan.nextLine();
        scorenospace = score.split(" ");
        rolla = Integer.parseInt((scorenospace[0]));
        rolld = Integer.parseInt((scorenospace[1]));
        if (rolla > rolld) {
            david = david - rolla;
        } else if (rolla < rolld) {
            antonia = antonia - rolld;
        } else if (rolla == rolld) {
        }
        rounds--;
    }
    System.out.println(antonia + david);
}
```

The user is going to enter 2 numbers separated by a space. I would like to individually collect and compare the 2 numbers entered as a string. How would I go about doing this?

My code throws an outofbounds exception. I'm very confused.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int rounds, antonia = 100, david = 100;
    int rolla, rolld=0;
    String score;
    System.out.println("How many rounds would you like to play? (1-15)");
    rounds = scan.nextInt();
    while (rounds > 0) {
        score = scan.nextLine();
        rolla = score.charAt(0);
        rolld = score.charAt(2);
        if (rolla > rolld) {
            david = david - rolla;
        } else if (rolla < rolld) {
            antonia = antonia - rolld;
        } else if (rolla == rolld) {
        }
        rounds--;
    }
    System.out.println(antonia + david);
}
```

I have also tried the chatAt method but cannot seem to get the code to work. ANY help would be greatly appreciated. I do apologize for the mediocre quality of code. I am new to programming and am trying to learn as much as I can by myself. Thanks very much for all the help,
Cheers :)

Comment: With what inputs does it throw an IOOB? Legal inputs?

Comment: whats the input you are providing?

Comment: with char at you'd actually get the char, so you'd need to do something like `rolla = (int)score.charAt(1) - 48;`

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
 at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:646)
 at doubledicesimple.main(doubledicesimple.java:15)`
That is the error that it throws, the program won't run far enough to let me enter any the score, it throws the exception right after I enter how many rounds i'd like to play

Comment: it isnt throwing any error to me? what are the inputs u r trying and in what sequence?

Comment: If anybody could even provide me with instructions on how to separately store each character from a string (perhaps into an array?) and then convert the characters into integers to do basic arithmetic with other integers, then I would essentially be able to solve the problem I am having with a lot of my programs.

Comment: I have tried to run the same code in 2 other compliers and they all give me the same error. The program asks me for the number of rounds I would like to play and immediately throws the outofbounds exception.
`How many rounds would you like to play? (1-15)
12
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
 at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:646)
 at doubledicesimple.main(Untitled.java:14)
` THIS IS WHAT THE CONSOLE SHOWS ME!

Comment: You are getting the error as expected. As soon as you have entered 12 rounds will be equipped with it. after entering 12 you need to provide more numbers like 12 or 13 after a space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess if you want input to be somewhat like this:

```
3 12 17 // where 3 is rounds and 12 and 17 are values
23 45 // 23 and 45 again as values
12 36 // 12 and 36 again as values
```

then you can change your code to as :

```
rounds = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
while (rounds > 0) {
    score = scan.nextLine();
    rolla = Integer.parseInt(score.split(" ")[0]);
    rolld = Integer.parseInt(score.split(" ")[1]);
    .
    .
    .
}
```

adding another thing:
score.charAt(0) would provide you ascii equivalent.

Comment: I would need the input to be something like this:
2 `//number of rounds`
3 4  `//values`
4 6`//values again`

Comment: but your first input of still seems to be rounds and values where as the actual program requires the first input to just be rounds and then the following inputs to be the actual values

Comment: try out with the input you proided... **2 //number of rounds 3 4 //values 4 6//values again** answer will be 190. `rounds = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());` asks for round where you will enter 2 and press enter. in console next line onwards you can start entering your values

Comment: My compiler continues to give me the following errors:
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
 at doubledice.main(doubledice.java:15)
`

Comment: I enter the number 2 when the program asks me how many rounds I would like to play and then the program immediately throws the errors

Comment: can you provide a snapshot of your code with console output?

Comment: the code seems to work after making the corrections that you suggested Vivek

Comment: could you please explain what was wrong with my code and instruct me on how to utilize each character from a string and use it as an integer if I would need to? This seems to be an issue with a lot of my code and I would like to learn how to do it the right way once and for all

Comment: There was nothig wrong in your code except the way you entered and thought what should be entered and charAt. charAt will always return you ascii if you convert it to int. A simple ex can be int a = 'a' which will provide u with ascii of it.

Comment: It is always good to go with Integer.parseInt to get a string and convert it to integer.

Comment: why exactly can I not just enter scan the input of the variable 'rounds' as an int? Why do I need to use .nextLine() and then parse that as an int? Rounds is an int value, it is not one of the variables that needs to be converted. I notice that when I use .nextInt() for rounds, I get the same exception as I was getting before

Comment: yeah ofcourse you can but the scanner advances past the input that matched. So it wont terminate the input there.